# How to execute terminal command in swift?

Tags: node.js, swift, bash, macos, terminal

I am new toSswift. How can I run this process from Swift code?

1. open Terminal window
2. execute `cd Desktop/firebase-mac`
3. execute `npm start`

What I am actually trying to do is to start Node server on click from Swift code.

Comment: I have tried         
task.launchPath = "/usr/bin/env"
task.arguments = ["/Users/aharon/Desktop"]
and i get Permission denied

Comment: There are various reasons to want to run commands in the Terminal, but opening a terminal from a program to do that is almost always the wrong thing. Let the user run the program in a terminal if they want to.  If you are unfamiliar with the shell, just take my word for it; you usually don't need the terminal to run a program, and when you do, that should be the invoking user's choice.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Full examples:

- go to some directory, let say `Desktop`
- Create a file with name `swsh`, and add into it (plaintext, not rtf, or doc)

```
#!/usr/bin/env xcrun swift

import Foundation

func shell(launchPath: String, arguments: [String]) -> String {

    let process = Process()
    process.launchPath = launchPath
    process.arguments = arguments

    let pipe = Pipe()
    process.standardOutput = pipe
    process.launch()

    let output_from_command = String(data: pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile(), encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!

    // remove the trailing new-line char
    if output_from_command.characters.count > 0 {
        let lastIndex = output_from_command.index(before: output_from_command.endIndex)
        return output_from_command[output_from_command.startIndex ..< lastIndex]
    }
    return output_from_command
}

let output = shell(launchPath: "/bin/date", arguments: [ ])
print(output)
```

Save, and:

- open the Terminal
- type `cd ~/Desktop`
- use `chmod 755 swsh`
- and run your `swift script` as: `./swsh`

You will get output like:

```
Sat Mar 25 14:31:39 CET 2017
```

Edit your `swsh` and change the `shell(...` line to:

```
let output = shell(launchPath: "/usr/bin/env", arguments: [ "date" ])
```

run it and again will get the date, but now:

- the `swsh` executed the `/usr/bin/env`, (with the argument `date`)
- and the `/usr/bin/env` finds the command `date`
- and executed it

Now, create another file in the `~/Desktop` and name it as `from_swift`.

Add into it

```
echo "Today's date is $(date)"
```

change the file `swsh` change the `shell` line to:

```
let output = shell(launchPath: "./from_swift", arguments: [ ])
```

Note, the `./from_swift` - using relative path to `.` (we are in the `~/Desktop` directory). Run the swift program:

```
./swsh
```

Output:

```
2017-03-25 14:42:20.176 swift[48479:638098] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'launch path not accessible'
```

Of course, the script `from_swift` **is not** executable yet. So execute:

```
chmod 755 from_swift
# and run
./swsh
```

Again error:

```
2017-03-25 14:45:38.523 swift[48520:639486] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Couldn't posix_spawn: error 8'
```

This is because the `from_swift` is a script (not a compiled binary), so the operating system need to know which binary should interpret the script content. Because this is an `shell script` edit the `from_swift` script as:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Today's date is $(date)"
```

Note the added "shebang" line: `#!/bin/sh`. Run the swift `./swsh` and will get

```
Today's date is Sat Mar 25 14:50:23 CET 2017
```

Horray, you executed your 1st `bash` script from `swift`. ;)

Of course, you can use the `/usr/bin/env` in the `shebang`, so now change, the content of the `from_swift` for example to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use utf8;
use English;
binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";

printf "The $EXECUTABLE_NAME (ver:$PERL_VERSION) runs me: $0\n";
printf "I ❤️ perl!\n";
```

Run the `./swsh` and will get:

```
The /usr/bin/perl (ver:v5.18.2) runs me: ./from_swift
I ❤️ perl!
```

NOTE, we changed **nothing** in the `./swsh` file, just the script file `./from_swift`!

All the above done using:

```
$ uname -a
Darwin nox.local 16.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.4.0: Thu Dec 22 22:53:21 PST 2016; root:xnu-3789.41.3~3/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
$ swift --version
Apple Swift version 3.0.2 (swiftlang-800.0.63 clang-800.0.42.1)
Target: x86_64-apple-macosx10.9
```

So, it is easy to create and execute **any** script. So, you can enter into your `~/Desktop/from_swift`

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $HOME/Desktop/firebase-mac
npm start
```

It is possible to do **directly** from the `swsh`, (Jens Meder proposed), but using this you got very easy method executing anything from the given script file.

Just remember: the `process.launch()` executes either:

- compiled binaries
- or script files, but the script files

  - **must** have the `shebang` line
  - and must be executable using `chmod 755 /path/to/script.file`

Answer (score 3):

You can just use the following code snippet, e.g., `run("npm start")`. It will execute the command on the default shell `/bin/sh` and return the output as a `String`.

```
func run(_ cmd: String) -> String? {
    let pipe = Pipe()
    let process = Process()
    process.launchPath = "/bin/sh"
    process.arguments = ["-c", String(format:"%@", cmd)]
    process.standardOutput = pipe
    let fileHandle = pipe.fileHandleForReading
    process.launch()
    return String(data: fileHandle.readDataToEndOfFile(), encoding: .utf8)
}
```

If you want to use a different bash then just replace the `launchPath`, e.g., for Zsh it would be `/bin/zsh`.

Comment: for  "/bin/sh" i get "command not found"
for  "/bin/env" i get "launch path not accessible"

Comment: Could you try `/bin/bash`, please?

Comment: Could you run `echo $SHELL` in a new Terminal window and try that output? For me it outputs `/bin/zsh` because I use Zsh as shell.

Comment: the result is  /bin/bash

Comment: I create a shell script
**#!/bin/bash
cd /users/aharon/desktop/firebase-mac
npm start**
It works fine when i run it ,
But if i run it from the code i get **line 3: npm: command not found**

Comment: @aharovishinsky it is `/usr/bin/env` and not `/bin/env`.

Comment: @aharovishinsky you simply **must** understand how OS executes commands, what is the differnce between the `/full/path/to/npm` and the pure `npm`, where the shell searching for the commands (the `$PATH` variable) how works  and the `/usr/bin/env` command ( `man env`) and much more... like what is the difference betwwen a binary and script, how and why you need make the script executable (using `chmod`) etc..etc... Added an step-by-step answer explaining some of the above...

Answer (score 1):

using [swift-commands](https://github.com/QiuZhiFei/swift-commands)

```
import Commands

Commands.Bash.system("cd /Users/${name}/Desktop/firebase-mac && npm start")
```

Answer (score 0):

To launch a process passing one argument you simply need one line:

```
Process.launchedProcess(launchPath: "/Users/aharon/Desktop/firebase-mac/npm", arguments: ["start"])
```

But consider that the literal path does not work if the application is sandboxed.

Comment: I create a shell script
**#!/bin/bash
cd /users/aharon/desktop/firebase-mac
npm start**
It works fine when i run it ,
But if i run it from the code i get **line 3: npm: command not found**

Comment: Have you tried my code as it is? Forget the extra `cd` command. You don't need it. Just pass the full path `/users/aharon/desktop/firebase-mac/npm start`

Comment: i get "launch path not accessible"