# Shell command via NSTask's Process delayed until my Vapor app quits

Tags: swift, vapor, nstask

I built a Vapor 4 app that is currently deployed on a local Ubuntu 18 server VM, running behind NGINX and serving users without any issues.

Now **I would like one of my web server routes to react to specific POSTs by executing a Bash command via `Process`** (this, in order to send messages to a dedicated Slack channel via [slack-cli](https://github.com/rockymadden/slack-cli), a tool I already use for other purposes and that is already configured and working both on my development machine and on the Ubuntu server).

**With the following code, everything's working as desired when I run my Vapor app *on my local machine*** (i.e.: immediately after the POST to the route the expected message appears in the Slack channel):

```swift
// What follows is placed inside my dedicated app.post route, after checking the response is valid...
let slackCLIPath = "/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/" // This is the slack-cli path on the Linux VM; I swap it with "/opt/homebrew/bin/" when running the app on my local Mac                 
_ = runShellScript("\(slackCLIPath)slack chat send '\(myMessageComingFromThePOST)' '#myChannel'")
// ...

// runShellScript() called above is the dedicated function (coming from [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43014767/3765705) that executes the Shell process, and its code follows:

func runShellScript(_ cmd: String) -> String? {
        let pipe = Pipe()
        let process = Process()
        process.launchPath = "/bin/sh"
        process.arguments = ["-c", String(format:"%@", cmd)]
        process.standardOutput = pipe
        let fileHandle = pipe.fileHandleForReading
        process.launch()
        return String(data: fileHandle.readDataToEndOfFile(), encoding: .utf8)
    }
```

My issue is that, **when I deploy my app on the Ubuntu server, both in debug and production, the execution of the Shell process does not happen like it did on my Mac: I have no errors logged by Vapor when I POST to that route, but no messages appear in Slack, even if I wait a while!**

But here's the tricky part: **as soon as I stop my Vapor app on the server, all messages are sent to Slack *at once***.

After a lot of testing (which obviously included confirming that from the server was possible to post without delays to Slack by using the exact same command passed to `NSTask`'s `Process` class in my Vapor app), **it appears like the Bash command is not executed *until my Vapor app quits***.

Clearly I'm missing something on how to make `Process` work "in realtime" with Vapor, and I'll be grateful for all the help I can get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wait until the task has finished. Looks like you're deadlocking yourself. This is how I run stuff on Linux:

```swift
// MARK: - Functions
@discardableResult
func shell(_ args: String..., returnStdOut: Bool = false, stdIn: Pipe? = nil) throws -> (Int32, Pipe) {
    return try shell(args, returnStdOut: returnStdOut, stdIn: stdIn)
}

@discardableResult
func shell(_ args: [String], returnStdOut: Bool = false, stdIn: Pipe? = nil) throws -> (Int32, Pipe) {
    let task = Process()
    task.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/bin/env")
    task.arguments = args
    let pipe = Pipe()
    if returnStdOut {
        task.standardOutput = pipe
    }
    if let stdIn = stdIn {
        task.standardInput = stdIn
    }
    try task.run()
    task.waitUntilExit()
    return (task.terminationStatus, pipe)
}

extension Pipe {
    func string() -> String? {
        let data = self.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        let result: String?
        if let string = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            result = string
        } else {
            result = nil
        }
        return result
    }
}
```

Important lines being starting it with `try task.run()` and waiting with `task.waitUntilExit()`

Comment: Thank you! And you also taught me about @discardableResult, very useful! ;)